# Importing external sass in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm importing bulma into Vue (installed via `vue init webpack-simple` ) and I can't seem to figure out how to get it to load my own external sass files.

I have it set up like this:

```
<style lang="sass" src="./sass/initial-variables"></style>
<style lang="sass" src="bulma"></style>
```

The tag pulling bulma in works just fine, but I get an error looking for my initial variables file:

```
ERROR in ./src/App.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './sass/initial-variables' in
'/Users/johnbriggs/Sites/mimismarket/src'
```

In my **src** folder, I have a sass directory with `initial-variables.sass` as a file.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing the `.sass.` extension in your `<style>` tag. Webpack might take that relative import literally.

One thing I like to do to keep my single-file components clean is to have one `<style>` tag and then `@import` my SASS files:

```
<style lang="sass">
@import 'bulma'
@import './sass/initial-variables' // we don't need the extension here
</style>
```

Another thing to keep in mind is that you can `import` CSS/SASS files in your JavaScript, too. It's really handy for global stylesheets:

```
// main.js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following in your webpack.config:

```
loader: 'vue-loader',
options: {
    extractCSS: true,
    loaders: {
        sass: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            use: 'css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax&data=@import "./sass/initial-variables.sass"', 
            fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
        })
    }
}
```